# How do change address field titles to another language in Ubercart?

Tags: 8, ubercart

In D7 you could just rename the title and type them in a different language.

[image]

But in D8, there is no such option like in D7.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the [Ubercart translation](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads?project=ubercart) solves the issue. Import the file using the `Interface Translation` module.

Comment: I think you should mark this (your own) answer as accepted. That way there is 1 unanswered question less, right?